# Magento2 set timezone with mysql query

Tags: magento2, database, date, timezone, datetime

I am trying to get days difference between 2 dates with mysql query with DATEDIFF function for production_days column:

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('cvo' => 'cp_vendor_order'), "cvo.parent_order_id = main_table.entity_id AND cvo.vendor_name ='".$configVendorName."'",array('production_days' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('DATEDIFF(ship_by_date,NOW())')))
```

The issue is NOW() provides different timezone rather than IST(Indian Standard Time) and i want to use IST timezone when we call NOW() , can anyone let me know how to achieve this thing?

Comment: You want to achieve this only by mySQL ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(new \DateTime())->format(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime::DATETIME_PHP_FORMAT);
```

**OR**

```
(new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d');
```

**OR**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objDate = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime');
$date = $objDate->gmtDate();
```

Comment: its not working.